# Spring boot: TilesDialect() throw exception

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, tiles2

I use Spring boot and i want to use tiles, but i have a problem:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine]: Factory method 'getTemplateEngine' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.thymeleaf.dialect.AbstractDialect: method <init>()V not found
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.thymeleaf.dialect.AbstractDialect: method <init>()V not found
at org.thymeleaf.extras.tiles2.dialect.TilesDialect.<init>(TilesDialect.java:46) ~[thymeleaf-extras-tiles2-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at com.scheduler.config.mvc.MvcConfiguration.getTemplateEngine(MvcConfiguration.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
at com.scheduler.config.mvc.MvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7a5dfe74.CGLIB$getTemplateEngine$1(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at com.scheduler.config.mvc.MvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7a5dfe74$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$41c485b2.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at com.scheduler.config.mvc.MvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7a5dfe74.getTemplateEngine(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
```

My part of WebMvcConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Bean(name = "templateResolver")
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver getTemplateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML");
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean(name = "templateEngine")
public SpringTemplateEngine getTemplateEngine(SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver) {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(resolver);
    templateEngine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
    templateEngine.addDialect(new TilesDialect());
    return templateEngine;
}

@Bean(name = "viewResolver")
public ThymeleafViewResolver getViewResolver(SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine) {
    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine);
    viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    viewResolver.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    viewResolver.setExcludedViewNames(new String[]{"*"});
    return viewResolver;
}
```

When the bellow line is execute, above exception is throw:

```
templateEngine.addDialect(new TilesDialect());
```

pom.xml dependencies:

```
<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring Boot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Thymeleaf -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-tiles2-spring4</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Could you help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the brand new `Thymeleaf 3.0.0.RELEASE` does not support Tiles yet. You have to wait for an update of `thymeleaf-extras-tiles2-spring4` come back to Thymeleaf 2 or resign from Tiles as I did :P

Comment: Thanks for help :) I've set thymeleaf to "2.1.2.RELEASE" and it's working! :)

Comment: any news on when it will release? It's been ten months since this post

Answer (score 0):

I had some problem with integration between spring-social and thymeleaf 3.0.3.

**My solution:**

1) Exclude module from autoConfiguration for module (in my situation spring-social):

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {SocialWebAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MyApplication { ...
```

2) Create config class:

```
@EnableSocial
@Configuration
public class SocialConfig implements SocialConfigurer {
...
}
```

3) Override ModuleDialect class (for me: SpringSocialDialect.class):

```
public class CustomSpringSocialDialect extends AbstractDialect  {

  public CustomSpringSocialDialect() {
    super("social");
  }

  public String getPrefix() {
    return "soc";
  }

  public Set<IProcessor> getProcessors() {
    return new SpringSocialDialect().getProcessors();
  }
}
```

4) Add dialect to templateEngine in MvcConfig.class:

```
@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(ITemplateResolver   templateResolver) {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
    templateEngine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
    templateEngine.addDialect(new CustomSpringSocialDialect());
    templateEngine.addDialect(new Java8TimeDialect());
    templateEngine.setMessageSource(messageSource());

    return templateEngine;
}
```

I think your problem have in this direction. So your *TilesDialect* has constructor without arg it's your problem. After that you can to use last version thymeleaf